# css sprites: Not working correctly in IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

My html form is:

```
<div id="account-box">
        <form method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:&nbsp;<span class="input-bg"><input class="login-input" name="loginUser" type="text" /></span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label for="password">Password:&nbsp;<span class="input-bg"><input class="login-input" name="loginPass" type="password" /></span></label>
            <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Login" />
            <a href="#">Register</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
        </form> <!-- End of form -->
    </div> <!-- End of account-box div -->
```

and my css for the above html is:

```
#account-box { padding-top:10px; width:100%; text-align:center; background:url(images/account-bg.jpg) repeat-x; position:fixed; bottom:0; height:35px;  font-weight:bold; }


#account-box .login-input { color:#444; padding:3px 5px; width:153px; height:19px; border:0; background:url(images/textbox.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
#account-box .login-input:focus { background:url(images/textbox.png) 0 -25px no-repeat; }


#account-box .submit-button { width:60px; padding:1px; border:2px solid #06c; }
#account-box .submit-button:focus { border:2px solid #900; }
```

There are two problems;

1. In IE6, the account-box div goes to the end of the page and not to the bottom of the current resolution. It works as a footer in IE6.
2. In IE6 and IE7, when I am using the sprite, it does not change the sprite when the text input is focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE6 doesn't support `position:fixed`.

IE6 and IE7 doesn't support the `:focus` pseudo class.

You could use `position: absolute; position: fixed;` to get partical functionality in IE6, that would at least place the element somewhere instead of stretching it.

You would need to use events to handle the `focus`/`blur` to get it to work in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: postion:absolute did the trick, but it is not moving with the scrolling. It stays as an overlay which i dont want.
Also, can you elaborate the focus/blur description

Comment: @booota: As `fixed` simply doesn't exist in IE6 there is no pure CSS solution. You can use Javascript to move the element when the page scrolls, so that you get the same effect as `fixed`. To use `focus`/`blur` events you can for example use `onfocus="this.className='login-input focus';" onblur="this.className='login-input';"` on the inputs, then use `#account-box .login-input.focus {...}` to target the element in CSS when it has focus.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. Hats off to you